# xpath to check only within WebElement in Selenium / Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am very new to this and i have tried to look for the answer to this but unable to find any.

I am using Selenium+chromedriver, trying to monitor some items I am interested in.

Example:
a page with 20 items in a list.

Code:
#list of items on the page

search_area = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@data-testid='test']")

search_area[19].find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='sc-hKwDye name']").text

- this returns the *name of item[0]*

search_area[19].find_element_by_css_selector('.name').text

- this returns the *name of item[19]*

why is xpath looking at the parent html?

I want xpath to return the name of item within the WebElement /list item. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

found the answer, add a . in front

hope this is gonna help someone new like me in the future.

from
search_area[19].find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='sc-hKwDye name']").text

to
search_area[19].find_element_by_xpath("**.**//p[@class='sc-hKwDye name']").text

Comment:  After a ton of searching for my specific issue, this is exactly what I was looking for — adding the "." before the xpath. I kept getting the first instance on the page without it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are passing in `find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='sc-hKwDye name']")` is relative Xpath. You can pass the full Xpath to get the desired result.